# Errors when streaming h264 video from gstreamer to ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, gstreamer

Hi I am trying to receive a udp/rtp stream with ffmpeg in the client side but is having trouble.

Server side pipeline:

```
 gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=video2.mp4 ! decodebin ! x264enc  !
 rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5006
```

On the client side, I can play the video with the following pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e udpsrc uri=udp://0.0.0.0:5006 ! application/x-rtp, clock-rate=90000, payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

However, since I want to convert the stream into a rtsp/http stream, I tried to receive the rtp stream with ffmpeg and perform something like:

```
ffmpeg -i udp://127.0.0.1:5006 -acodec copy -vcodec copy http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

But before doing that, I was testing this approach by saving the stream into a mp4 file with:

```
ffmpeg -f h264 -i udp://127.0.0.1:5006 -strict -2 -f mp4 stream.mp4
```

But this did not work, it gave me the following error:

> missing picture in access unit with size 15019525 [h264 @ 0x11d5100]
>   no frame! [h264 @ 0x11f06c0] decoding for stream 0 failed [h264 @
>   0x11f06c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264):
>   unspecified size Consider increasing the value for the
>   'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options [h264 @ 0x11f06c0]
>   Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
>   udp://127.0.0.1:5006: could not find codec parameters

Have anyone tried such approach before or experienced similar problem, I would like to get some direction on how to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: who gave the downvote? care to comment why? this is very nice question with real effort :)

Comment: I think you can do that all in gstreamer - check [this](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-rtsp-server/tree/docs/README?h=1.8). I have no experiences with ffmpeg.. in vlc you would play this with `rtp://@:5006` which I think is using ffmpeg..